# Chipscope ILA unable to capture signals correctly

Tags: fpga, xilinx, logic-analyzer

ALL the [ILA modules](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/test_ddr3_memory_controller.v#L86-L126) that I am having now do not work .

I mean they failed to even capture the user-assigned '[clk](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/ddr3_memory_controller.ucf#L1)' and '[resetn](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/ddr3_memory_controller.ucf#L52)' signals. Why ?

Note: the PCB schematics could be found [here](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/PCB_schematics.pdf)

[image: ILA]

Comment: Suggests it isn't being triggered. Do something dumb like wire a pushbutton to both an output driving a LED and the trigger input. The LED tests the pushbutton state so you know THAT bit's working. Once you can trigger off the button and see CLK and RESET, you can move on.

Comment: @user_1818839 I wired the 'resetn' (a tact switch) signal to a LED, the LED turns on and OFF according to the tact switch.  So, the issue is still with ILA configuration inside ISE

Comment: @user_1818839 these are my ILA settings : [page 1](https://i.imgur.com/QIcl5Ti.png) , [page 2](https://i.imgur.com/vE7W0EG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by increasing the value of "Position" field to something larger, say 300

[image: ILA waveform]